# Second jQuery load datepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I do have some problem with datepicker after jQuery load.

In the beginning I do have load:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    if(inputInit.val()==0){
            initDateDDMMYY('#formName');
            inputInit.val('1');
            console.log (inputInit.val());
        }
     )
    }
```

Source code for function:

```
function initDateDDMMYY(formname){
    var $frm = $(formname);
    $frm.find('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
        $frm.find('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat : "dd.mm.yy",
            autoclose : true,
            changeYear : true
        });
};
```

On first load there is no problem, but on the next load - date picker is nor working. Even not initialized. Even if I try too init it again with firebug - nothing happens.

Load is normal:

```
$("#div").load("${action}");
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java?

Comment: can your provide a fiddle?

Comment: Why java - because everything is on jsp/liferay environment - I could mentioned it - it should not be a difference - but s..t can happens

Answer (score 0):

There is a js error in your code!

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 if(inputInit.val()==0){
    initDateDDMMYY('#formName');
    inputInit.val('1');
    console.log (inputInit.val());
  }
 });
```

Here you forgot the ");" at the end